# Struts 2 Accessing action tag properties with # syntax

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, struts2

Is it possible to access fields defined in Beans/Forms used within an action from a JSP page?

At the moment I can use this:

```
<s:action name="actionName" var="foo" executeResult="false" />
```

and access any fields defined in that action class using

```
<s:property value="#foo.bar" />
```

but this doesn't seem to work for values defined in a bean or form, which I would normally be able to access using the property tag in the result JSP page for an action.

Comment: "values defined in a bean or form" What does that mean? WOuld you post some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tested this with Struts 2 version 2.3.4.1 and it worked for me to get the displayName value of the kuPerson bean.  Note in my Struts action class I have a getKuPerson method that returns an object of type KuPerson and that KuPerson class has a getDisplayName method that returns a String.

```
<s:action name="person" var="personAction" executeResult="false" />

Display name: <s:property value="#personAction.kuPerson.displayName" />
```